# How can I send email to a list with Mandrill in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, api, email, express, mandrill

I can't seem to find a clear answer to this anywhere. I have a database full of email addresses that I need to fetch, then attach to a Mandrill email message in NodeJS. I have a basic message constructed and can send to one recipient. I need to attach my list of 1000 recipients to the message. Here's what I have. It was taken from an example in the Mandrill docs, then modified. Where and how do I include my list? I see that the to: property is an array, do I just add a variable there that is an array of objects, then send that off to Mandrill? Thanks for your help!

```
var message = {
            "html": html,
            "subject": "Subject",
            "from_email": "recipient@gmail.com",
            "from_name": "recipient",
            "to": [{
                    "email": "recipient@gmail.com",
                    "name": "Recipient Name",
                    "type": "to"
                },
                {
                    "email": "recipient@gmail.com",
                    "name": "Pickle McGillicuddy",
                    "type": "to"
                }],
            "headers": {
                "Reply-To": "recipient@gmail.com"
            },
            "important": false,
            "track_opens": null,
            "track_clicks": null,
            "auto_text": null,
            "auto_html": null,
            "inline_css": null,
            "url_strip_qs": null,
            "preserve_recipients": null,
            "view_content_link": null,
            "bcc_address": "recipient@gmail.com",
            "tracking_domain": null,
            "signing_domain": null,
            "return_path_domain": null,
            "merge": true,
            "global_merge_vars": [{
                    "name": "merge1",
                    "content": "merge1 content"
                }],
            "merge_vars": [{
                    "rcpt": "recipient@gmail.com",
                    "vars": [{
                            "name": "merge2",
                            "content": "merge2 content"
                        }]
                }],
            "tags": [
                "password-resets"
            ]
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add each email address to the `to` array in `message`. I think you're looking for something along these lines:

```
var message = { ... };

var emailAddresses = ... // get from database    

for (var i in emailAddresses) {
    message.to.push({
        email: emailAddresses[i],
        type: 'to'
    });
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I couldn't find any documentation on this. Guess I overlooked something. Thanks!